# Blurry app' form in windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, sharpdevelop

Is there any way to make form looks OK while windows text size options is set to more than 100% (e.g. 125%)?

Because since this setting is any then 100% the whole application (form) looks blurry! Of course we can open .exe' properties and say to ignore that windows "screen scale" option but I've seen many programs which just looks great independently, looks like they totally ignore default windows "text and elements scale". How do I make my app ignore this option as well?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `AutoScale` property of the form to `None`. That should 'disable' the scaling of the form.

Comment: the form is normal size now, but elements are still blured